# this.props equal to nextProps componentShouldUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following scenario:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LocaleStringsService from '../Services/LocaleStringsService.js';
import LocaleStringsList from '../Components/LocaleStringsList.js';

class Translate extends Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            strings: []
        }

        this.firstRender = true;
        this.stringsService = new LocaleStringsService();

        console.log('constructor');
    }

    fetchStrings() {
        const { match: { params }} = this.props;
        const that = this;

        console.log('fetchStrings() for locale ', params.locale);

        const strings = this.stringsService.fetchForLocale(params.locale)
            .then(function (results) {
                that.setState({ strings: results });
                console.log('ASYNC fetchStrings().stringsService found some strings', results);
            })
            .catch(function () {
                that.setState({ strings: [] });
                console.log('ASYNC fetchStrings().stringsService ERROR CATCHED! emptyin\' strings');
            });

        console.log('fetchStrings() for locale DONE', params.locale);
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('componentWillUpdate()');

        this.fetchStrings();
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate()');
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate() current locale:', this.props.match.params.locale);
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate() next locale', nextProps.match.params.locale);
        if (this.firstRender) {
            console.log('shouldComponentUpdate() firstRender = false');
            this.firstRender = false;
            return true;
        }
        if (this.props.match.params.locale === nextProps.match.params.locale) {
            console.log('shouldComponentUpdate() SHOULD NOT UPDATE BECAUSE LOCALES MATCH');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount()');

        this.fetchStrings();
    }

  render () {
    console.log('render() RENDERING...');
      return (
         <LocaleStringsList strings={this.state.strings} />
      );
  }
}

export default Translate;
```

The issue is that `shouldComponentUpdate()` does not allow me to compare `this.props` to `nextProps` because the two values ALWAYS match.

You can also see that for some reason the AJAX request is triggered twice because the first request performs a setState, which triggers another update.

This is the console.log of what happens:

```
constructor
render() RENDERING...
componentDidMount()
fetchStrings() for locale  it_IT
fetchStrings() for locale DONE it_IT
shouldComponentUpdate()
shouldComponentUpdate() current locale: it_IT
shouldComponentUpdate() next locale it_IT
shouldComponentUpdate() firstRender = false
componentWillUpdate()
fetchStrings() for locale  it_IT
fetchStrings() for locale DONE it_IT
render() RENDERING...
ASYNC fetchStrings().stringsService found some strings [LocaleString]
shouldComponentUpdate()
shouldComponentUpdate() current locale: it_IT
shouldComponentUpdate() next locale it_IT
shouldComponentUpdate() SHOULD NOT UPDATE BECAUSE LOCALES MATCH
ASYNC fetchStrings().stringsService found some strings [LocaleString]
```

The entire system depends on shouldComponentUpdate() to tell the component if data should be fetched again. Params only change when the same route is being accessed, but with different params (in my case, different locales, same page).

Since I am not able to do that, requests always fail after the first render (a workaround I've implemented to make sure that AT LEAST the first run always goes through, because you can see in the console that the params match, even though the first run should have had the param as NULL or something different).

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: edited-- added in the question

Comment: I have just noticed the requests are done in reverse :S If I request locales in it_IT, en_EN is requested, and viceversa.

Comment: By the way, `shouldComponentUpdate` is never called for first render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was triggering an update in componentWillUpdate instead of using componentWillReceiveProps, since that's what's actually changing. Also shouldComponentUpdate shouldn't be used to do that kind of props checking since it is not necessary in this case.

```js
[...]

fetchStrings(locale) {
    var that = this;

    const strings = this.stringsService.fetchForLocale(locale)
        .then(function (results) {
            that.setState({ strings: results });
        })
        .catch(function () {
            that.setState({ strings: [] });
        });
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.locale !== nextProps.match.params.locale) {
        this.fetchStrings(nextProps.match.params.locale);
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStrings(this.props.match.params.locale);
}

[...]
```

Comment: You should still check that the props have actually changed before calling `fetchString`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have

```
`arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`

    arrCopy = arr.slice() // […arr]

    arrCopy[0] = -1; // arr[0] will still be 1
```

This is because numbers are primitives.
Whereas if you had 
`arr = [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}]`

```
arrCopy = arr.slice()

arrCopy[0].value = -1 // arr[0].value will also become -1
```

Nested objects are never copied, thats why it is called shallow copy.

*Objects Inside the array is carrying the reference of the object here.*

*Even if you make another reference (using ... or .slice()) of array and then change any object in index.*
***You know what?*** The real array which you copied will still be changed, because you changed the object(i.e you changed the value in the address, reference is still pointing to the same address!!

HOPE THIS HELPS